# Convert dynamic json to java object with dynamic string value. No key value json structure

Tags: java, json, object

I want to convert below JSON structure to java object, Annotation bases.

> What will be the pojo java class structure?

```
{
      "Data1":{
            "Name":"abc",
            "Number":2
           }
     }
```

Data1 can by any string-like if it coming as data1 first time, next time it can be like "xyz".

> How can we convert it using fasterxml json annotations?

Comment: The json is produced by you? is possible to create another field called "dataName" and put at the same level of Name and Number? Without this change is not possible use an annotation based deserializer

Comment: No. I'm consumer. Need to convert it directly in pojo

Comment: So you have to use a map structure and not an annotation based deserializer: see here https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-mapping-dynamic-object#using-map

Comment: I need to pass my java object to third party. In that this response will come

Comment: What you mean? Try to do a complete example in your question

Answer (score 0):

```
class Node {
    public String name;
    public int number 
}

class ConvertedPojo {
    public Map<String, Node> attributes;
}
```

Since Data1 can be any string you need a map which will store all different string as key and value as json object

Comment: Tried this one. Empty map is coming

Answer (score -1):

Class structure will be :

```
public class Data1{
    @JsonProperty("Name")
    private String name;
    @JsonProperty("Number")
    private int number;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        name = name;
    }
    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }
    public void setNumber(int number) {
        number = number;
    }
}

public class Data {
    @JsonProperty("Data1")
    Object data1;
    public Object getData1() {
        return data1;
    }
    public void setData1(Object data1) {
        this.data1 = data1;
    }

}
```

Take care of the variable naming convention.

Code to test:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Data data1 = mapper.readValue("{\"Data1\":{\"Name\":\"abc\",\"Number\":2}}", Data.class);
        System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(data1));//{"Data1":{"Name":"abc","Number":2}}


        Data data2 = mapper.readValue("{\"Data1\":\"data value\"}", Data.class);
  
  System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(data2));//{"Data1":"data value"}
    }
```

Comment: Data1 is string value. No any class/node. It can be changed

Comment: Data1 cannot be fixed since is a variable string